# Keyboard not navigating to certain sections of android app

Tags: android, accessibility

I am using date and time picker from android in my app but while trying to navigate Date setting using keyboard, the shade cursor does not enter the calendar and moves to next item like save, cancel. Meanwhile Time picking is working fine.

[image: Image of my Date and Time picker with shade cursor on CANCEL]

Comment: Are you using Tab or the arrow keys on your keyboard?

Comment: In this case, neither of the two are working, otherwise I'm able to navigate through both of them. Is there a difference in implementation or anything?